# How to debug values of java packages in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse (Juno) and Java 7.

The JRE has attached source code from the JDK download (src.zip).

I am able to trace and execute source code from JDK. However, I am unable to see variable values. For example, I am unable to see the variable values in java.util.ResourceBundle, but I can see step-by-step execution of its code in Eclipse.

I am able to debug and see variable values in my own code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the JRE class files are compiled without debug information, so you cannot really debug the code: debugger does not show local variables etc. It might be that your Eclipse is not setup to run with JDK, it might run with JRE instead.

Follow this link to debug the JDK classes:

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-view-and-debug-jdk-source-code-in-eclipse.html

Comment: Juned Ahsan, I saw that post when I was trying to solve my problem. In my case, I have no "Source not found" problem. I can debug/trace my code into java.util package. I am able to run the code in java.util package step-by-step. I am simply unable to see the values of local variables there. I just switched to JDK instead of JRE by going to Windows->Preferences->Installed JREs. I still have the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: @curious1 Try to remove the existing Debug Configuration and create a new one.

Comment: I am using Jetty to run a debug a Spring web application. Did what you said, but there is no success. As before, I am only able to see the values of method arguments (arg0, arg1, etc. in Variables pane), not values of local variables. Thanks.